# Add Columns Based Off Values From Another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query pulling user information.

```
SELECT UserID, CompanyID, FName, LName FROM tblUsers  Where OrgType = 'business'
```

I have another query pulling user info.

```
SELECT u.UserID, u.AccessID, t.AccessName FROM tblUserAccess as u Inner Join tblAccessType as t on u.AccessID = t.AccessID
```

Finally there is a third query that pulls acces types.

```
SELECT AccessID, AccessName, OrgType FROM tblAccessType WHERE OrgType = 'business'
```

There can be X number of different access types in tblAccessType. The different access types will grow over time. Also, a user can have X number of access types .

How do I write a query that will return data in the following format?

```
UserID CompanyID FName LName SALES MARKET ADMIN FIN

100    200       Jane  Doe     *                 *

101    200       John  Doe                   *

120    205       Mary  Smith   *             *

121    205       Mark  Smith   *                  *
```

His is sample data below.

```
tblUsers

UserID CompanyID   FName LName  OrgType

100     200        Jane  Doe    business

101     200        John  Doe    business

120     205        Mary  Smith  business 

121     205        Mark  Smith  business

122     259        Fred  Wilson charity

tblUserAccess

UserID AccessID 

100    1

100    4

101    3

120    1

120    3

121    1

121    4 


tblAccessType

AccessID AccessName OrgType

1        SALES      business

2        MARKET     business

3        ADMIN      business 

4        FIN        business 

5        NOTAX      charity

6        SECURITY   government
```

Comment: You'd need to pivot the access types by Userid, then join it to the users... Can you post some sample source data please and anything you may have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a `PIVOT`... I went with a dynamic `PIVOT` so if you add new `AccessTypes`, they will automatically be added.

If you wish to omit the `NULL` data, then change the `''*'' AS AccessVal` to be `1 AS AccessVal` and then change the `MAX([AccessVal])` to `COUNT([AccessVal])` -- this will give you 1/0 instead of */NULL

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblUsers') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tblUsers
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblUserAccess') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tblUserAccess 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblAccessType') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tblAccessType 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tblAccessPivot') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ##tblAccessPivot 

CREATE TABLE #tblUsers (UserID INT, CompanyID INT, FName VARCHAR(255), LName VARCHAR(255), OrgType VARCHAR(255))
CREATE TABLE #tblUserAccess (UserID INT, AccessID INT)
CREATE TABLE #tblAccessType (AccessID INT, AccessName VARCHAR(255), OrgType VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO #tblUsers (UserID, CompanyID, FName, LName, OrgType) 
VALUES (100, 200, 'Jane', 'Doe', 'Business'), 
       (101, 200, 'John', 'Doe', 'Business'), 
       (120, 205, 'Mary', 'Smith', 'Business'),
       (121, 205, 'Mark', 'Smith', 'Business'),
       (122, 259, 'Fred', 'Wilson', 'Charity')

INSERT INTO #tblAccessType (AccessID, AccessName, OrgType)
VALUES (1, 'Sales', 'Business'), 
       (2, 'Market', 'Business'), 
       (3, 'Admin', 'Business'), 
       (4, 'Fin', 'Business'),
       (5, 'NoTax', 'Charity'),
       (6, 'Security', 'Government')

INSERT INTO #tblUserAccess (UserID, AccessID)
VALUES (100,1),(100,4), -- JANE
       (101,3), -- JOHN
       (120,1),(120,3), -- MARY
       (121,1),(121,4) -- MARK

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @sql  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF(
(SELECT N',' + QUOTENAME(y) AS [text()]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AccessName AS y FROM #tblAccessType) AS Y
ORDER BY y
FOR XML PATH('')),
1, 1, N'');        

SET @sql = 'SELECT UserID, CompanyID, Fname, LName, '+@cols+'
            INTO ##tblAccessPivot
            FROM (SELECT U.UserID, U.CompanyID, U.Fname, U.LName, AT.AccessName, ''*'' AS AccessVal
                  FROM #tblUsers U
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN #tblUserAccess UA ON U.UserID=UA.UserID
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN #tblAccessType AT ON UA.AccessID=AT.AccessID) SUB
            PIVOT (MAX([AccessVal]) FOR AccessName IN ('+@cols+')) AS P'
PRINT @SQL
EXEC (@SQL)

SELECT *
FROM ##tblAccessPivot
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of going about this if your access types remain (mostly) static.  It doesn't involve pivoting, which is always a plus.

```
DECLARE @tblUsers TABLE
(
    UserID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tblUsers SELECT 100, 'John Doe'
INSERT INTO @tblUsers SELECT 101, 'Jane Doe'

DECLARE @tblUserAccess TABLE
(
    UserID INT,
    AccessID INT
)

INSERT INTO @tblUserAccess SELECT 100, 1
INSERT INTO @tblUserAccess SELECT 100, 4
INSERT INTO @tblUserAccess SELECT 101, 3

DECLARE @tblAccessType TABLE
(
    AccessID INT,
    AccessName VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tblAccessType SELECT 1, 'SALES'
INSERT INTO @tblAccessType SELECT 2, 'MARKET'
INSERT INTO @tblAccessType SELECT 3, 'ADMIN'
INSERT INTO @tblAccessType SELECT 4, 'FIN'


SELECT u.UserID
    , u.Name
    , [SALES] = MAX(CASE WHEN at.AccessName = 'SALES' THEN '*' ELSE ' ' END) 
    , [MARKET] = MAX(CASE WHEN at.AccessName = 'MARKET' THEN '*' ELSE ' ' END) 
    , [ADMIN] = MAX(CASE WHEN at.AccessName = 'ADMIN' THEN '*' ELSE ' ' END) 
    , [FIN] = MAX(CASE WHEN at.AccessName = 'FIN' THEN '*' ELSE ' ' END) 
FROM @tblUsers u
JOIN @tblUserAccess ua
    ON u.UserID = ua.UserID
JOIN @tblAccessType at
    ON ua.AccessID = at.AccessID
GROUP BY u.UserID, u.Name
```

And results:

```
UserID  Name    SALES   MARKET  ADMIN   FIN
100 John Doe    *                       *
101 Jane Doe                    *
```